# fix javascript issue on a page - wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, error-handling, lazy-loading

I have a javascript loading problem on one of my pages…i had tried to load in a wordpress lazy load app but it seems to have caused errors into my page. i've since removed it, but the problem still exists: the page is jerky. see link below:

http://www.jasonrichardadams.com/?page_id=394

a grid had existed for this page…now because of the error it seems to have disappeared.

Comment: There's still an error thrown in custom-isotope-portfolio.js on line 28. The page doesn't seem particularly jerky to me.

Comment: by jerky I meant when I load the page it does not have the smooth gridded version previous to me loading in that app. how do I correct this error?

Comment: where is vals defined (or previously defined)?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: You can try creating a new Projects page.

Comment: Mostly what is happening is that, the .js file that contains defination for vals, is getting loaded after the isotope-portfolio.js

Comment: gotcha. i tried to create a new page…the problem still exists. can I reload the those .js files in my ftp to fix the issue - or is there another way?

Comment: disable all plugins n try 1ce.